# get_terms of specific parent (including the parent itself)

Tags: taxonomy, terms

The title is self-explanatory, but let me say a word on this...

I want to get the terms of a specific parent, but also include the parent itself in the returned terms. I tried something this `$args['parent'] = $args['include'] = $tax->term_id;` but unfortunately it didn't work...

I'm thinking to find the parent of the parent, and do something like this `$args['parent'] = {id of grandfather}; $args['exclude_treeint'] = array({ids of siblings of the parent});`

But isn't this an overkill of a solution? Am I missing something obvious here? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way you can setup the arguments such that you can get all children of a term and that term in one call, so you'll probably just have to tack on the parent as a separate call.

Using `get_terms` for the children, then `get_term`.

```
$parent_id = 100; // set as appropriate
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'YOURTAX',
    'hide_empty' => false, // omit if not applicable (used for testing)
    'child_of' => $parent_id,
) );

$terms[] = get_term( $parent_id, 'YOURTAX' );
```